# Vertical text showing in all browsers except Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

This is really blowing my mind right now!

```
span.verti{
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2); 
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3); /*IE6,IE7 */
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);   
    writing-mode:lr-bt;
    -ms-writing-mode:lr-bt;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    opacity:1 !important;
}
```

Image example in firefox: http://accelerateonline.net/work/ghai/images/firefoxscreenshot.png

Image example in IE 9: http://accelerateonline.net/work/ghai/images/fullscreenshot.png

Comment: Nice screenshots. Too bad we don't have the buggy code.

Comment: How are you creating the vertical text?

Comment: hey sorry, the code is in this very strange javascript file located http://accelerateonline.net/work/ghai/wp-content/themes/Vouge/js/cufon-yui.js

Comment: That's the only place it seems to have any sort of text transform code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell without the code.

IE does have a proprietary piece of code for rotation:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
```

`rotation=1` Content is rotated 90 degrees.

`rotation=2` Content is rotated 180 degrees.

`rotation=3` Content is rotated 270 degrees.

Might work?